# Qual diferença entre os módulos math e cmath?

Tags: python, matemática

No Python percebemos que existem os seguintes módulos: `math` e `cmath`, no entanto não entendi qual diferença entre os dois. Veja como podem ser importados:

```
import math
import cmath
```

Qual diferenças entre os módulos `math` e `cmath`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como está descrito [na documentação](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/cmath.html), o módulo `cmath` "*fornece acesso à funções matemáticas para [números complexos](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/N%C3%BAmero_complexo)*". Na verdade as funções desse módulo também aceitam números inteiros e reais, além de permitir trabalhar com números complexos. Já as funções "normais" do módulo `math` *não podem* ser usadas com números complexos.

Answer (score 6):

- `math`é o módulo das funções matemáticas.
- `cmath` é o módulo das funções matemáticas que trabalham com números complexos.

Answer (score 1):

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Criei este diagrama para exibir de forma mais clara e objetiva a distribuição hierárquica dos conjuntos numéricos.

Como podemos observar cada conjunto numérico é representado por uma determinada letra, ou seja:

1. **N** - Conjunto dos números Naturais;
2. **Z** - Conjunto dos números Inteiros;
3. **Q** - Conjunto dos números Racionais;
4. **IR** - Conjunto dos números Irracionais;
5. **R** - Conjunto dos números Reais;
6. **C** - Conjunto dos números Complexos.

A classe `math` é especializada para trabalhar com números pertencentes ao conjunto dos números `Reais`.

Como podemos perceber, o conjunto dos números `Reais`, é um subconjunto do conjunto dos números `Complexos`, isto é, as regaras utilizadas para se operar com números reais não são suficientes para abranger operações com números complexos. Por isso, quando desejamos operar com números reais utilizamos a classe `math`.

Já a classe `cmath` é especializada para trabalhar com números pertencentes ao conjunto dos números complexos.

Observando novamente o diagrama, podemos notar que **todos** os conjuntos estão contidos no conjunto dos números complexos. Por este motivo, os métodos implementados na classe `cmath` são bem mais abrangentes.

**O que isto significa?**

Isto significa dizer que, quando importamos a classe `math`, podemos trabalhar com todos os números, exceto os números `complexos`. E, quando importamos a classe `cmath`, podemos trabalhar com todos os números sem exceção alguma.

É lógico, que para operarmos com números reais não precisamos importar a classe `cmath`, porque já temos tudo do que precisamos na classe `math`.

Agora, a partir do momento que precisamos trabalhar com números complexo, é óbvio que devemos importar a classe `cmath`.